# Start websocket server without terminal Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm do real time application with Laravel and [Brainsocket](https://github.com/BrainBoxLabs/brain-socket)
Websocket server start with command php artisan brainsocket:start.

How to start websocket without terminal?

When i added to global.php Artisan::call('brainsocket:start') page has stopped working

Answer (score 0):

Look at this tutorial, you can define that the service starts when system boots :  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps